# xsd.exe not nesting properly

Tags: xml, vb.net, xsd

i am only a few days into xml. I finished my read xml to database and currently trying to get data back into a new file. i have generated my class with xsd.exe and it is not nesting the finished xml properly.

here is the xml schema i used for xsd.exe.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="communication">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="transaction">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Inspection">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Tracking" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
                    <xs:element name="Wh">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element name="Zip" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
                          <xs:element name="Country" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Inspect">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Examined" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                          <xs:element name="Infested" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                          <xs:element name="Signature" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element name="SignatureDate" type="xs:date" />
                          <xs:element name="InspectedDateTime" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element name="Finding" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="transactionType" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="holder" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="user" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="password" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="sequence" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="date" type="xs:unsignedInt" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="time" type="xs:unsignedInt" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="date" type="xs:unsignedInt" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="time" type="xs:unsignedInt" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="vendor" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

when i generate a sample in vs it is correct.
when i create the file from my console app, everything is seperated out like this:

```
<communication />
<transaction />
<PhytosanitaryInspection />
<Wh />
<inspection />
```

instead of

```
<communication>
<transaction>
<PhytosanitaryInspection>
<Wh />
<inspect />
</PhytosanitaryInspection>
</transaction>
</communication>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your own sanity, break out each element definition into it's own definition, and then include that definition in the parent.

e.g.

```
    <xs:element name="Inspect">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Examined" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
          <xs:element name="Infested" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
          <xs:element name="Signature" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="SignatureDate" type="xs:date" />
          <xs:element name="InspectedDateTime" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="Finding" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

and then

```
  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Inspection">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Tracking" />
        <xs:element ref="Wh" />
        <xs:element ref="Inspect" />
    </xs:element>
```

Refactor this all the way through the schema. This improves readability and maintainability (not just for yourself but for everyone else).
It may be that your console app is detecting a small error or inconsistency (or perceives it is) that VS is not picking up, so parsing the information differently.

Dividing the definition will also help with visualising the data logic.

W3C Schools has an [example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_example.asp) that expands on what I have written above.